# Why does etaremune start from zero on some lists in a document?

Tags: etaremune

I used the lines (shown below) in a document repeatedly to generate lists of items in reverse order in each list. I want each list to start with number 1. After several lists. Some lists had a starting number 0 (zero). I'd appreciate any suggestions to fix this problem.

```
\begin{etaremune}
\item pub5
\item pub4
\item pub3
\item pub2
\item pub1
\end{etaremune}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  you can identify your code inserts by indenting them 4 spaces, or highlight them with the mouse, and click the `{}` icon that appears over the input window.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your example is not sufficient to give an answer. Please provide the minimal example that has this issue. I am wondering why you say `I want to start with number 1` -- The `etaremune` package reverses the list numbering, so the example above should start with `5`, not `1`

Comment: You probably just need to run LaTeX again

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of package [`etaremune`](https://ctan.org/pkg/etaremune):

> The `etaremune` environment will avoid creating labels with negative
>   numbers as this can cause problems when using alphabets for labels. So
>   when adding items to an existing list, these will be numbered with 0
>   on the next run. Another LaTeX run will settle the item labels again.

Unhappily, the package does not print a warning, if this is the case and another LaTeX run is needed. The package does not use the referencing mechanism of LaTeX that would warn, if a reference value has changed.

Package `rerunfilecheck` can be used to get a warning, if a `.aux` file has changed. The package uses MD5 sums to detect a difference. MD5 sums are provided by pdfTeX or LuaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[aux]{rerunfilecheck}
\usepackage{etaremune}
\begin{document}
\begin{etaremune}
\item pub5
\item pub4
\item pub3
\item pub2
\item pub1
% \item pub new
\end{etaremune}
\end{document}
```

Test scenario:

1. LaTeX run: new  `.aux` file, warnings by packages `etaremune` and `rerunfilecheck`.
2. LaTeX run: Numbers are fine 5 to 1, no warnings.
3. Edit the file and enable the new item.
4. LaTeX run: Numbers from 5 to 0, not correct; `.aux` file has changed and package `rerunfilecheck` warns.
5. LaTeX run: Numbers are successfully reassigned from 6 to 1, no warnings.